# Need to extract row number and insert into cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use Google Forms/Sheets as an ordering tool.  I've already created the form and set up the script on my Results spreadsheet to summarize the order and send the user a confirmation email.  In that email, it takes the row number of the form submission and uses that as the order number.

These columns are populated via the form (Timestamp, Email Address, Site, Item Requested, Requestor / Room #, Site Budget Code & Additional Information) while the remaining columns are filled in manually.

My issue now is that the higher-ups want to be able to extract all of that data for record keeping purposes.  From what I can tell, Google Sheets does not have the ability to print the rows/columns, so I would like to extract the row number and insert it into the Order # column on the sheet.

Can anyone help with writing a script to make that happen?  Here is a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LlPf4KkV-c1az-vn2ES0TFOhAOipnicvkj3cPye95IY/edit#gid=763456666

Thanks!!﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in row 1 of the column where you want the Order #'s to be:

```
=arrayformula(if(ROW(A1:A) = 1, "Order #", IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,ROW(A1:A))))
```

This will place **Order #** in the the first row due to the first IF statement. In each subsequent row it will place the row number IF cell A in that row is not blank.  The Google Form will place a timestamp here so every submission should have a value for cell A.

Since the second IF statement has no value for a TRUE check on ISBLANK() it will place no value in any cell where row A has no value.  Had I used "" here it would actually place a value and potentially interfere with other formulas and scripts.

Comment: Thanks @Karl_S.  This code won't actually increment though right?  I think I just got it working correctly using the following code:
`function addOrder() {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] onFormSubmit");
  
  var orderNumber = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastCol);
  lastCell.setValue(orderNumber);   
}`

Comment: I gave you an answer that uses no custom code.  That was a Google Spreadsheet formula to get what you needed.  No script.  And it applies itself to the entire column.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.  Each time a new form submission is entered, I get the following error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in P29."

Comment: Your Code may still be running.  Make sure it is not and remove the items at the bottom of the column.  The formula will fill in the entire column and needs it to be blank otherwise.

Comment: You're right.  The script was messing with your code.  It's working again.  Thank you!